# Perl Inotify not responding to append (ie, echo 'test' >> file)

Tags: perl, inotify

When running the below test code to watch a file, events are only detected if I do a 'vim' on the file and write it out (or write-quit). Doing an 'echo' to the file, or adding text via perl is not detected.

test_inotify.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Carp;
use IO::File;
use Linux::Inotify2;

$|++;

my $readfile            = shift;
#my $action     = "IN_CLOSE_WAIT";
#my $action     = "IN_MODIFY";
#my $action     = "IN_OPEN";
my $action      = "IN_ALL_EVENTS";

unless ($readfile) { $readfile = "test.txt" };

my $inotify     = Linux::Inotify2->new();

$inotify->watch($readfile, $action)
                or die "Inotify watch on " . $readfile . "failed: $!\n";

while () {

    my @events  = $inotify->read();

    unless (@events > 0) {
        print "Inotify Read Error: $!\n";
        exit;
    };

    foreach my $event (@events) {
        print "Detected Event: " . $event->fullname . "\n";
    };

};
```

test_fh_write.pl:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;
use Carp;
use IO::File;

$|++;

my $readfile            = shift;

unless ($readfile) { $readfile = "test.txt" };

my $readfh              = IO::File->new( $readfile, ">>" ) or
#my $readfh              = IO::File->new( $readfile, ">" ) or
                                die "Cannot open $readfile: $!";

$readfh->autoflush(1);

if ($readfh) {

    print $readfh "test\n\n";

};

undef($readfh);
```

I've tried with test_fh_write.pl as well as echo commands like this: 'echo a >> test.txt', 'echo "test" >> test.txt', etc.

I have also tried with the "$|" character and without (even with $fh->autoflush(1)), but to no avail. Each of the $action variables defined in test_inotify.pl I've tried, but they all result the same.

Answer (score 4):

I think the second argument to `Linux::Inotify2::watch` is a number/bitmask, not a string. You should be calling

```
$inotify->watch($readfile, IN_ALL_EVENTS)
```

instead of

```
$inotify->watch($readfile, "IN_ALL_EVENTS")
```

The bareword `IN_ALL_EVENTS` is resolved to the (presumably constant) function `&Linux::Inotify2::IN_ALL_EVENTS`.